# Raspberry pi computer cluster question?

Tags: parallel-programming

I am wanting to have/ or make a program that runs on a (raspberry pi)computer cluster with one pi executing only video content while the other only handles music, etc under a main program like an AI. Am I in the right direction? Isnt this parallel computing?

Comment: BTW, probably a single cheap PC running Linux could be more powerful than 2 Raspberry Pis

Comment: In what aspect though? From what I have learned, a cluster would be better for distributed tasks compared to an emulation on a computer. Right? Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

You seem a bit confused about what parallel computing is.  [Parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) is about farming out parts of a computationally intensive task to multiple workers.  One type of parallel computing is distributed computing; an example would be a brute-force attempt to crack cryptography, where each node tries a few keys at a time, until one of them gets lucky and finds a working key.

If you have two computers performing two different tasks, then that's just two computers performing different tasks.

You haven't told us what the main program does, but I suspect that it has nothing to do with artificial intelligence.